# How can I make a field readonly after sending a Post Request in Django?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models

How can I make the start_date readonly after the Question is created? I have tried  modifying the admin.py  file but  the date field is still editable, I got no idea how to can solve that

This is the Question model

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    poll_question = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', blank=False,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.poll_question
    
    def choices(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_choices'):
            self._choices = self.choice_set.all()
        return self._choices
```

This is the code I added in the admin.py file in order to make the start_date readonly after creation but there is still no change.

```py
class DateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return self.readonly_fields + ('start_date')
        else:
            return []
```

Answer (score 0):

*To set an admin model field to read-only use* **, readonly_fields** attribute

```
@admin.register(Question)
class DateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    readonly_fields = ['start_date']
    # ...
```

**NB :** Making a field read-only assume that you have a way to set it without using the admin interface. You can override the `save()` method of the `Question` model to do that.

Comment: @Rverctor how can I override the save() method of the Question model? I tried the code above but the problem hasn't been solved I can still edit the start date field.